# PLSQL package annotation not found error

Tags: plsql, annotations, erp

given below is the annotation the PLSQL package that i have created. But when i try to create the iLDT file by running the script in $FND_TOP i am getting error.
"the package annotation was not found at the required second line after the declaration"

"the tag @rep: product belongs at the master level of the note for orphan annotation"

My annotation is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE XX_FS_MANAGE_TASKS_PUB AS

    /* $Header: $ */

    /*#

    * This is the public interface for Dynamic Field Service Tasks Data.

    * @rep:scope public

    * @rep:product csf

    * @rep:displayname XX_FS_MANAGE_TASKS_PUB

    * @rep:lifecycle active

    * @rep:compatibility S

    * @rep:category BUSINESS_ENTITY CSF_TASK_DEBRIEF

    */

   /***********************************************************************

   Package Name:     XX_FS_MANAGE_TASKS_PUB

   Purpose     :     This package outputs Field Service dynamic task values


History:

Version     Date             Created /          Comments

                             Modified By

=======    ===========     ============         ===================================

1.0        17/09/13        abcd               Initial Creation.

************************************************************************/
```

Answer (score 1):

I think its because of empty line after create or replace package statement, do you have these empty lines at your file also?

Comment: Yeah, it may be something like that. But not exactly that. Because, i tried that and it didnt work. I had to remove the pakage name and history part at the end to get it to work. Dont know if its the best thing to do.

Comment: Actually i do have also comments between my package annotation and method annotation its really interesting, maybe you had problem with method annotation, anyway its good to hear you got it worked :)